# Unordered map running unusually slow compared to map C++

Tags: c++, unordered-map

I am trying to use an unordered map to hash an array of size 2 and search the map later. Unfortunately this is significantly slower than when I use the regular c++ map which I don't think is right because insertion and look up are O(log(n)) in a map and O(1) in an unordered map. One thing to note is I was using a concatenated string value of the values in the array in the map instead of the array. I don't think this should matter though because the string concatenation is more expensive than creating the array of size 2. I have attached the relevant code.

Thanks everyone :)

```
struct arraySizeTwoEqualityStruct 
{

    bool operator()( const array< double, 2 >& leftArraySizeTwo, 
                     const array< double, 2 >& rightArraySizeTwo ) const 
    {

        return 
                abs( leftArraySizeTwo[ 0 ] - rightArraySizeTwo[ 0 ] ) < 0.0001 &&
                abs( leftArraySizeTwo[ 1 ] - rightArraySizeTwo[ 1 ] ) < 0.0001;

    }

};


struct arraySizeTwoHashStruct 
{

    size_t operator( )( const array< double, 2 >& arrayToHash ) const
    {

        return ( hash< double > ( ) ( arrayToHash[ 0 ] ) ^ hash< double > ( ) ( arrayToHash[ 1 ] ) ); 

    }

};
```

Comment: I believe your program exhibits undefined behavior. Elements that compare equal must have the same hash.

Comment: from help: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself." Please give a [mcve]

Comment: Have you profiled both to see where the slowdown or difference is?

Answer (score 3):

> **[unord.req]/5** Two values `k1` and `k2` of type `Key` are considered equivalent if the container’s key equality predicate returns `true` when passed those values. If `k1` and `k2` are equivalent, the container’s hash function shall return the same value for both.

Your `arraySizeTwoEqualityStruct` and `arraySizeTwoHashStruct` violate this requirement. The former declares two elements that are "close enough" to be equivalent, but the latter still gives them different hash. Therefore, your program exhibits undefined behavior.

---

> **[unord.req]/3** Each unordered associative container is parameterized by ... a binary predicate `Pred` that **induces an equivalence relation** on values of type Key.

Emphasis mine. `arraySizeTwoEqualityStruct` is additionally invalid in that it doesn't induce an equivalence relation. In particular, it's not transitive: there exist values `A`, `B` and `C` such that `A` is "close enough" to `B`, and `B` to `C`, but `A` is not "close enough" to `C`.